# Practical way to keep grouping variables associated with observations when doing PCA and cluster analysis

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, cluster-analysis, k-means

Consider the data frame `data` created here:

```r
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(State =rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 100),
                   Loc = rep(letters[1:20], each = 20),
                   ID = sample(600,400,replace = F),
                   var1 = rnorm(400),
                   var2 = rnorm(400),
                   var3 = rnorm(400),
                   var4 = rnorm(400),
                   var5 = rnorm(400))
```

`var1:var5` are measurements that were taken on individuals that were randomly sampled from a variety of locations denoted by the `Loc` column, which is nested within the larger grouping `State`. Each individual has a unique `ID` number. Notice the `ID` numbers are in no particular order, so measurements are relatively meaningless without their associated grouping variables. I am using the `FactoMineR` and `factoextra` packages to do PCA and cluster analysis. 
lets say I do a PCA and decide that I want to keep the first 3 principle components (I will store the coordinates in an object called `ind.cords`:

```r
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)
pca<- PCA(data[,4:8], scale.unit = T, graph = F)
a <- get_pca_ind(pca)
ind.cords <- a$coord[,1:3]
```

Next I go through the preliminary steps of determining the optimal number of clusters, and I decide on 5. I run the final kmeans to get the clusters:

```
set.seed(123)
clustering <- kmeans(ind.cords, centers = 5, iter.max = 50, nstart = 25)
clustering
```

Here is where I am having trouble: `fviz_cluster()` makes it easy to plot clusters:
`fviz_cluster(clustering, geom = "point", data = ind.cords) + ggtitle("k = 5")`
But I want to visualize which observations belong to which clusters using both grouping variables. So I need those columns to use as labels. I can go back to where I created `ind.cords` and add the `State` `Loc`, and `ID` columns back to it: `ind.cords <- cbind(data[,1:3], ind.cors)`.
From here I can either carry forward by specifying which columns I want to perform operations on (e.g., kmeans(ind.cords[,4:6]) or I can make a new object called `input` that just has the numeric columns (e.g., `input <- ind.cords[,4:6]`), but in either case, I cant figure out how to get the `fviz_` functions to label observations by `State` or `Loc`. Could someone demonstrate a practical way to do this or explain how to restructure the way I am approaching this analysis so that I can visualize which observations and groups are in which clusters? 
Ultimately (unless someone has a better suggestion for visualizing clusters with many groups) I believe it would be easier to visualize the clusters if colored text is used instead of points for the grouping variables (`State` or `Loc`), and ellipses are drawn around the points to show what clusters they belong to, so this is what I am shooting for in the graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to just layer on top of it, as I cannot figure out to map anything else in `fviz_cluster()`. You can adjust the alpha so that you can make them out. Example with `geom_point()`

```r
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(State =rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 100),
                   Loc = rep(letters[1:20], each = 20),
                   ID = sample(600,400,replace = F),
                   var1 = rnorm(400),
                   var2 = rnorm(400),
                   var3 = rnorm(400),
                   var4 = rnorm(400),
                   var5 = rnorm(400))

library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)

pca <- PCA(data[,4:8], scale.unit = T, graph = F)
a <- get_pca_ind(pca)
ind.cords <- a$coord[,1:3]
ind.cords <- cbind(data[,1:3], ind.cords)

clustering <- kmeans(ind.cords[,4:6], centers = 5, iter.max = 50, nstart = 25)

fviz_cluster(clustering, geom = "point", data = ind.cords[,4:6], shape = 16) + ggtitle("k = 5") +
  geom_point(aes(shape = ind.cords$State), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]
You can also use `geom_text()`:

```r
fviz_cluster(clustering, geom = "point", data = ind.cords[,4:6], shape = 16) + ggtitle("k = 5") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(ind.cords$State, ":", ind.cords$Loc)), alpha = 0.5, size = 3, nudge_y = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT: Setting `geom = NULL` also works, so you can suppress the `geom_point()` done by `fviz_cluster()`:

```r
fviz_cluster(clustering, geom = NULL, data = ind.cords[,4:6], shape = 16) + ggtitle("k = 5") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(ind.cords$State, ":", ind.cords$Loc)), size = 3, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

EDIT: And the same with colors for clusters:

```r
fviz_cluster(clustering, geom = NULL, data = ind.cords[,4:6]) + 
  ggtitle("k = 5") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(ind.cords$State, ":", ind.cords$Loc),
                color = as.factor(clustering$cluster)),
            size = 3, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: this was helpful, thanks, in the case when we use `geom=NULL` do you know how to color the text?

Comment: @Ryan It's possible, I've added that to the answer!